# How to show different items (that is based on first dropdown) in the second dropdown after first dropdown is selected in Powerapps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

Below is the sample data: 
Area Table:
[image]

Building Table:
[image]

The two dropdown lists:
[image]

The desired output I would  like to achieve is:
If first dropdown item is "EC - Empire Complex" then the second dropdown item will show storey 1 and storey 2.If u see the datatable buildingID = 1 is EC - Empire Complex and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a label and set its visible property to false so it just acts as a place to store a variable and set its Text property to:

```
LookUp('Area Table', building = Dropdown1.Selected.Value).buildingID
```

This should set the label to "1" when the EC- Empire Complex is selected. Make sure that this works and then for your second dropdown you can set Items to:

```
Filter('Area Table', buildingID = Label1.Text).storey
```

I found this link helpful to learn more about finding items in data sources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup